# Install intl PHP extension OSX High Sierra

Tags: php, intl, macos-high-sierra

How can I install intl PHP extension in PHP 7.1.7, which is delivered with osx high sierra?

Answer (score 61):

So I had the exact same issue. As noted by other folks commenting here, High Sierra comes with PHP 7.1 installed and this PHP version has intl compiled with it

In my case, I followed part of Neodork comment's in the following [Valet+ issue](https://github.com/weprovide/valet-plus/issues/127#issuecomment-378914908):

"Install" PHP 7.1 (so it comes from brew itself, not the one installed by High Sierra)

`brew install php@7.1`

Upgrade it to latest version

`brew upgrade php@7.1`

Symlinks for references in Cellar:

`brew link --overwrite --force php@7.1`

Change PHP path in my bash profile

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.1/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Reload your bash profile (you can close the terminal and open it again)

`. ~/.bash_profile`

Check for Intl

`php -m | grep intl`

**Note:** If you come across with warnings like:

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/opt/php71-intl/intl.so'`

Then you have to disable the previous intl:

`mv /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/ext-intl.ini /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/ext-intl.ini.disabled`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: brew link --overwrite --force php@7.1 //
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.1/7.1.25...  //
Error: Could not symlink sbin/php-fpm //
/usr/local/sbin is not writable.

Comment: @NathanJ.Brauer that's a good one. Seems people have been having issues with that also. Check if the directory exists. If an `ls -la /usr/local/sbin/` pops something, then check for the permissions for it. Otherwise, you'll have to create it and adjust the right permissions  with something like 
`sudo mkdir /usr/local/sbin && sudo chown -R \`whoami\`:admin /usr/local/sbin`
The information was extracted from here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/4527

Comment: @NathanJ.Brauer I got the same error. I exported the new path anyway, opened a new terminal and `which php` pointed to `/usr/local/opt/php@7.1/bin/php`. Check if it works for you

Comment: For those of you similarly brewtarded as I am, the referenced 7.1 above should be updated to reference your required version. As of right now, Brew fails to find a 7.1 reference, because 7.4 is the one I needed. 

Double check your needed version before you proceed, unlike my last hour... ;)

Comment: Thanks mate. Been looking for this since 3hrs now.

Comment: I had the same issue - `Error: Could not symlink sbin/php-fpm // /usr/local/sbin is not writable`. I did `sudo mkdir /usr/local/sbin && sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/sbin` and then need to source .bash_profile or open another terminal to see the correct php install path.

Answer (score 19):

After the integration from `brew/php` to `brew/core`, the `intl` extension is included by the default installation. I also had the same problem the `intl` extension wasn't working. The problem I had was the command-line environment was not using the installed version of PHP but the default version from macOS system.

To enable the installed version, you need to do this:

After 

`brew install php@7.1`

You need to link the installed PHP version by

`brew link php@7.1`

Then you need to OPEN A NEW TERMINAL to make it effective.
Then double check the PHP binary path,

`which php`

make sure it's

`/usr/local/bin/php`

instead of 

`/usr/bin/php`

Then check if the intl extension is enabled,

`php -m | grep intl`

It works for me.

Comment: i tried many solutions for now but this one works for me thanks alot.

Answer (score 11):

open a terminal then type:

```
brew search intl
```

you should be able to see php71-intl, then run

```
brew install homebrew/php/php71-intl
```

then restart apache

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

then type:

```
php -i | grep intl
```

you should be able to see something like this:

```
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/ext-intl.ini
intl
intl.default_locale => no value => no value
intl.error_level => 0 => 0
intl.use_exceptions => 0 => 0
```

Enjoy!

Comment: The homebrew/php tab has been deprecated as of April 1st, 2018. The new way PHP and its extensions are delivered now is... a mess. Some extensions are bundled, some aren't.

Comment: When I `brew search php71-intl` I get `no formula found for php71-intl` and then I get list of closed PRs. I can't find a way to install the intl package with homebrew. I have the `homebrew/php` and `homebrew/core` taps even though the php tap is deprecated. If I try to `brew install php71-intl` I get errors saying formula not available, not found and not found in taps

Comment: The person who deprecated php tap is a full ***.
Everything broke after latest sierra update and brew upgrade.

If you deprecate something in favor of something else, CHECK if that something else even works...

If someone managed to get intl up and running again, please reply. I tried install through pecl but that just throws even more errors.

Comment: php-intl is now bundled with the php formulae in Homebrew. Simply uninstall your current php version and reinstall the homebrew/core php : `brew install php71 --with-pear`

Comment: `$ brew uninstall php71` and then `brew install php71 --with-pear`

Comment: php has moved to `homebrew/core`. The formula is renamed to `php@7.1`. It includes `intl` *by default*, there is no need to load or install the extension manually.

Comment: @miguelr Its working but im getting bunch of warnings about `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/opt/php71-intl/intl.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php71-intl/intl.so, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.60.dylib`. Any idea?

Answer (score 7):

I'm running the brew 1.6.2, on OS High Sierra. The intl extension is not available in brew packages so far.

The @Mondy solution worked fine for me. After run the

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.1
```

The packages will be available in /usr/local/php5 or /usr/local/php5-7.0.27-20180201-135220.

So in your /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php.ini you can place the following lines to enable the intl extension:

```
[intl]
extension="/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/intl.so"
```

In my case I prefered to create a file 'ext-intl.ini' in /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d/, just for a better organization.

Comment: where is place intl.so?

Comment: I was able to install on macox high sierra. but had issue with it first `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: intl: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20170718
PHP    compiled with module API=20160303
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
`

Comment: This worked for me! I used 
extension="/usr/local/php5-7.1.21-20180903-114446/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/intl.so".  You will find the exact path in the output of the install.

Comment: This worked for me too, I just downloaded directly the needed file from `https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/php-osx.liip.ch/install/5.6-10.10/frontenddev/5.6-10.10-frontenddev-5.6.36-20180703-123509.tar.bz2` (which for php 5.6 in my case), and copied `intl.so` to `xamppfiles/lib` and updated `php.ini` with the corresponding link.

Answer (score 7):

try this on Mac

```
php -v
sudo port install php7*-intl
```

#### More information

You can find port packages by this page https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=intl

And you can install `port` through these steps: https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.html

```
curl -O https://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/MacPorts-2.5.4.tar.bz2
tar xf MacPorts-2.5.4.tar.bz2
cd MacPorts-2.5.4/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

And change ~/.bash_profile

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

#### If there is error, check following steps:

check port

```
sudo port list
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port search --name --glob 'php*'
sudo port install php**-intl
```

This page has more info about port usage: https://guide.macports.org/chunked/using.html

Comment: Interesting concept, but the MacPorts project is an absolute mess, there isn't even a working version for macOs Catalina, which is over 1 year old now and installed on literally every mac in the world

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what [L. Grolleau says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46653030/119775) (run `brew install php71-intl`), paste the `int.so` path to the `/php.ini` at the end of the file:

```
extension=/usr/local/Cellar/php71-intl/7.1.11_20/intl.so
```

Answer (score 3):

I find a solution.

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.1
```

Then I copied intl.so from the installation to my extension directory, which is defined into my php.ini.

Comment: Can you go a little more into detail? Where is the intl.so located after executing the above command.

Comment: php -i | grep extension

Comment: Actually when trying sudo cp /usr/local/php5-7.1.13-20180201-134129/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/intl.so /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/intl.so I get Operation not permitted - going to try switching the version of php rather than just the extension. more info here https://php-osx.liip.ch and https://websitebeaver.com/set-up-localhost-on-macos-high-sierra-apache-mysql-and-php-7-with-sslhttps

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to work this out.

First uninstall any php packages you have completely with brew, then run the `brew update` and `brew doctor` commands.

Now install with `brew install php@7.1` (changed the version as needed) intl is included in the build for all php-formulae.

To confirm it is working run `php -m | grep intl`. You will see the intl extension is included. If not check the php.ini file and make sure the extension is being loaded.

Comment: You will not need to check the php.ini, as the extension is built in.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following file with

```
rm /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/conf.d/ext-intl.ini
```

Worked for me, thanks to [homebrew-core Issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/26074)

Answer (score 0):

I installed php7.2 with brew and linked with that version on Mac, but cannot see even the version number 7.2 in `phpinfo()`.
It always showed the last version(7.1) even though uninstall with brew, so the intl extension.
I found we have to modify httpd.conf file(in my case in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf), in that file you can find the

```
LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

in that line you have to override with your new php72 path: in my case it was

```
 LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.2/7.2.31_1/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
```

And restart apache, it works fine.

Answer (score -6):

try this

```
brew install homebrew/php/php71-intl
```