# Installing mcrypt and intl using Hombrew/Core

Tags: homebrew, macos-high-sierra

I am trying to install mcrypt and intl on my Mac using hombrew but the formulea are not valid since homebrew/php has been deprecated and merged into homebrew/core.

I have installed the latest verion of php (brew install php) and it seems that mcrypt and intl are not included in the modules. Has anyone solved this?

OS: Mac Os High Sierra

Answer (score 0):

The answer is available as a comment [Install intl PHP extension OSX High Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46652968/install-intl-php-extension-osx-high-sierra#comment87013011_47968488)

What worked for me was first uninstalling all previous versions:

```
$ brew uninstall php71
```

Then installing with pear enabled:

```
$ brew install php71 --with-pear
```