# How to enable PHP Intl extension on macOS Mojave?

Tags: php, macos, php-extension, macos-mojave

I'm trying to install Magento (2.3.0) on macOS Mojave. Magento shows `PHP Extension intl.` is missing.

I tried the below to resolve:

1. Made a copy of php.ini using `cp /etc/php.ini.default php.ini`
2. Removed ";" before `extension=php_intl.dll`
3. Restart Apache `sudo apachectl restart`

But the above did not resolve.

On checking `php -v`, i'm seeing the below error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
'/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_intl.dll' - 
dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_intl.dll, 
0x0009): dlopen(): file not found: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug- 
non-zts-20160303/php_intl.dll in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.1.19 (cli) (built: Aug 17 2018 20:10:18) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

There are only 2 files under `/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303` namely `opache.so` and `xdebug.so`

How can i install or enable "PHP Extension intl" on my macOS Mojave?

Comment: `extension=php_intl.dll` should be `extension=php_intl.so`, because this is not Windows.

Comment: Thanks. Tried that but same issue `al-OSX:sbin konathal$ php -i | grep intl
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_intl.so' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_intl.so, 0x0009): dlopen(): file not found: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/php_intl.so in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install intl PHP extension OSX High Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46652968/install-intl-php-extension-osx-high-sierra)

Answer (score 7):

Here's a solution that worked for me:

1. Find all PHP versions installed `brew list | grep php`
2. Remove all versions of PHP `brew remove --ignore-dependencies --force php70 php71 php72` (based on what you see above)
3. Install PHP `brew install php72` (i chose 7.2, 7.3 is not supported yet by several vendors)
4. Run the command `which php` should show you the path to the installed PHP. Copy the path.
5. Update your bash_profile `vi ~/.bash_profile` and add this line to the file:
   `export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH`
6. Save and run this `source ~/.bash_profile`
7. Check if *PHP Intl Extension* is installed using `php -m | grep intl`. If the installation went well, we will see **intl** listed. If not the extension is not installed.

I think from PHP 7 (not sure of the version), the extensions are available by default and we need not enable them in **php.ini** file explicitly.

Comment: Helpful answer, but I don't think adding `export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH` in `.bash_profile` is necessary? I installed PHP with `brew` and there is no `/usr/local/php5` directory on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Homebrew's php, linking it to a directory in your path will fix the issue. 
`brew link --force php@7.3`
I had the same issue and that fixed it. 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55301299/mac-os-intl-extension-is-not-loaded) is a link where I got a detailed answer from

Answer (score -1):

Got help from the link and able to compile  https://donatstudios.com/Install-PHP-Mcrypt-Extension-in-OS-X

Next we will download the PHP source. Verify the exact version of PHP you are running. This can be retrieved as follows. The version is highlighted.

```
$ php --version
PHP 7.1.19 (cli) (built: Aug 17 2018 18:03:17) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group

Now we move into a working directory and download the source making sure to update the following for the version from above.


$ cd /tmp
$ curl -L http://php.net/get/php-{{php-version}}.tar.bz2/from/this/mirror > php.tar.bz2
$ open php.tar.bz2

Now we will compile and test the extension.

$ cd php-{{php-version}}/ext/{{extension}}
$ phpize
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make test
$ sudo make install

If all that goes well finally we'll need to add the following to our php.ini - I usually add at it at the end of the file.

extension = {{extension}}
.so
You can verify your installation with the following:

$ php --info | grep {{extension}}\\.

Lastly, depending on your setup now you may want to restart apache.

$ sudo apachectl restart
```