# Mac OS: Intl extension is not loaded

Tags: php, prestashop, intl

- macOS Mojave 10.14.3
- PHP 7.1.23
- Prestashop 1.7.5.1

---

I tried to install PHP intl extension on my local server in order to use Prestashop.

I added `extension=php_intl.so` to `etc/php.ini`

When I try to install Prestashop I get `Intl extension is not loaded`.

### $ php -m | grep intl

When I do `$ php -m | grep intl`, I get:

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
'/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20160303/php_intl.so' - d
lopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20160303/php_intl.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20160303/php_intl.so' - dlopen
(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20160303/php_intl.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
intl`

It seems that the file `php_intl.so` doesn't exist.

### $ sudo pecl install intl

I also tried `$ sudo pecl install intl`and I get:

`make: *** [php_intl.lo] Error 1
ERROR:`make' failed`

### $ curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.1

I also tried `$ curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.1` and it doesn't create the `intl.so` file.

---

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47968488/2693543

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install intl PHP extension OSX High Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46652968/install-intl-php-extension-osx-high-sierra)

Comment: did you see this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54206286/how-to-enable-php-intl-extension-on-macos-mojave

Comment: None of these solutions work for me since `brew install php71-intl` is not available anymore and `curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.1` doens't create the `intl.so` file

Comment: Did you try `brew install icu4c` before the `sudo pecl install intl`?

Comment: @SiadArdroumli confirm that, didn't solve the problem, because still get this after sudo pecl install intl: 
2 warnings and 1 error generated.
make: *** [php_intl.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed

Answer (score 33):

Brew's PHP 7.1, 7.2 and 7.3 **all have INTL enabled by default**.

---

Most probably, you're just using your Mac OS' bundles version of PHP.

Run

`ls -l $(which php)`

to find out where the current PHP binary is located and whether it is symlinked to a Brew installation or not. In my case, for example:

```
lrwxr-xr-x 1 27 May 23 16:30 /usr/local/bin/php -> ../Cellar/php/7.3.5/bin/php
```

Meaning that my `php` is linked to Brew's 7.3.5 version.

If you are **NOT** using Brew's PHP, you'll see something like

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 11169664 Mar 21 07:09 /usr/bin/php
```

### Installing PHP through Brew

Find out whether you've already installed PHP:

```
brew list | grep php
```

If there is any output, and your version of PHP is present, go to step 2, or use step 1 to update PHP to the latest version.

**1. Install Homebrew's PHP**

```
brew install php@7.3
```

(or 7.2, 7.1). If Brew complains about not being able to find a formula, you might have messed with taps. Instead of `php@7.3`, you could try to supply the full path to the [current php formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/php):

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/master/Formula/php.rb
```

Still not working, check whether you are running a recent version of Homebrew `brew --version`.

```
Homebrew 2.1.3-31-geaf2370
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision fd1ef; last commit 2019-05-25)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 16d50; last commit 2019-05-26)
```

**2. Link Homebrew's PHP**

Now, to have `php` 'in your path', there are two options.

**a)** **Either** homebrew's version must be *linked* from its install location (/usr/local/bin/Cellar/php....) to a directory in your path (e.g., /usr/local/bin). To do this, run:

```
brew link --force php@7.3
```

If you are not able to link, this is typically caused by set permissions or System Integrity Protection. In the first case, try `sudo chown "$USER":admin /usr/local/bin/php`.

**b)** **Or**, add the `/usr/local/opt/php@7.3` directory (*[opt-prefix](https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook)*) to your $PATH variable. E.g., for **Bash**:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin:/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

**3. Validate installation**

`ls -l $(which php)`

should show that `php` is linked to a Homebrew PHP installation in `/usr/local/bin/Cellar`.

`php -v`

should show the recently installed version of PHP. Try to restart your terminal if that's not the case.

`php -i | grep -i intl`

should show some information about the current install of `intl`.

If you're using webservers and/or PHP FPM, this is the time to restart those services. (Or restart your system, if you don't know how to do that and cannot figure out).

### Possible issues

**If you still get warnings about missing extensions (Unable to load dynamic library, etc.), then your php.ini is messed up.**

Find the current location of php's ini

```
$ php -i | grep \.ini

Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php/7.3
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini
....
```

Edit /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/php.ini and find the offending extension load (e.g., `extension="myext.so"`). Comment out those that cannot be found.

Homebrew permissions

[Some argue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432071/how-to-fix-homebrew-permissions) that it's a good idea to chown `/usr/local`.

`sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local`

This will make installing things here, by hand and through Homebrew, a lot easier, but also a bit less secure too, since non-root processes are now allowed to write here too.

**Your web-application is using a different version of PHP.**

Make sure that it doesn't... The configuration of this depends on the used webserver. A first step would be to output the current PHP configuration in your web-application with `<?php phpinfo();`.

[This explains steps for Apache.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523183/how-to-use-the-php-that-brew-installed)

Another way to get a webserver + PHP stack running quicly is using [Laravel Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/valet).

### Installing additional extensions

To install additional PHP extensions, use PEAR.

`pear -V`
should output the current PEAR and PHP version.

```
PEAR Version: 1.10.9
PHP Version: 7.3.5
Zend Engine Version: 3.3.5
```

Now, to install an extension, for example, PHP's yaml extension:

```
pear install yaml
```

Comment: Thank you! Add this to your answer please. It was my issue after installing brew php I should also rewrite my PATH variables to point to new php.  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile

Comment: @Volodymyr, that's indeed an option to get PHP in your path, the other being `brew link --force php@7.3`. I will mention it though!

Comment: Very detailed. Thank you.

Comment: I have been trying for hours to debug this issue. Nothing was working and nothing made sense. Tried multiple stack answers which all came up empty, until I landed here. Thanks so much for the answer, you're my new hero. Very, very detailed and covers all bases!

Comment: During the brew install php@7.3 step I got "An unexpected error occurred during the `brew link` step..." This answer resolved that issue: https://github.com/httpie/httpie/issues/645#issuecomment-456902997

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a lot of answers about this problem and anyone helped me, but the last (of course). This is for XAMPP´s use.

Xcode is needed.
Download the version of php you use in xampp from php.net.
Extract it and open the extracted folder in a terminal using cd.
Change to subfolder ext/intl.
Run these commands to build the extension:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/bin/phpize
./configure --enable-intl --with-php-config=/Applications/XAMPP/bin/php-config --with-icu-dir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/
make
sudo make install (password required)
```

Delete all files you downloaded and also the extracted folders.
Add to php.ini file in xampp/etc folder line

```
extension="intl.so"
```

Original link: https://community.apachefriends.org/viewtopic.php?p=255061&sid=27afc55649dfe6ea7b0824cb0bb8486b

Answer (score 0):

Since php 7 it's not necessary load the extension `php_intl.so`, what do you need to do?, edit your `php.ini` and delete or comment the line that is loading the extension `php_intl.so`, after this reload your apache and try again.

Comment: I tried to do this but Prestashop doesn't detect intl

Comment: and are you sure that prestashop is working with the same `php.ini` that you configured?, create a `phpinfo()` in the same path of the prestashop install and check the information loaded, this screenshot shows how `intl` is enabled: https://i.postimg.cc/B4xNQ5VL/image.png

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue with [brew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/4831)

You could try to use this as mentioned there:

> brew tap kyslik/homebrew-php
>
> brew install kyslik/php/php71-intl

Comment: There is no more such thing as brew php on macOS Mojave 10.14.3. Instead there is 'native' PHP 7.1.23 without intl.so extension. Only output from what you suggesting for me is "Error: Invalid formula: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/kyslik/homebrew-php/Formula/php54-intl.rb
php54-intl: "cxx11" is not a recognized standard
Error: Cannot tap kyslik/php: invalid syntax in tap!"

Answer (score 0):

i tried all but intl not working in mac so please uninstall xampp and install mamp it will work

Answer (score 0):

So, on Pecl Official site ( https://pecl.php.net/package/intl ), it's clear that Intl package is not maintained anymore and has been superseded. Since PHP 5.3.0 you don't need to use Pecl to install intl extension, it's bundled with PHP.

But, it's missing on native instalation of PHP 7.1.24 on Mac OS Mojave.

if you wanna use only native apache and php pre-installed instead of using homebrew, do this:

Download PHP 7.1 from php.net, install XCode Command Line Tools, ICU (http://site.icu-project.org/), Autoconf, reinstall the developer tools header files, and finally install Intl extension using phpize.

Important: you'll have to disable SIP.