# How to configure PHP Intl extension on MacOS Mojave?

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, macos-mojave

I've been struggling to configure PHP Intl extension on MacOS Mojave. I've followed instructions provided on [Mac OS: Intl extension is not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55301299/mac-os-intl-extension-is-not-loaded) but couldn't get it working.

Following are relevant information:

```
$ls -l $(which php)
-r-xr-xr-x  1 imac  staff  14302704 24 Jun 15:56 /usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin/php

$echo $PATH
/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/sbin:/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin ...

$ php -m | grep intl
intl
```

From phpinfo:
Loaded Configuration File /etc/php.ini
There is no php_intl.so in this configuration file.

Amy I missing something? How do I verify if intl is loaded or not?

Comment: You've chosen to use MacOS' built-in web server but not its built-in version of PHP. You'll need to configure the web server to use the third party PHP installation.