# How do you get the intl extension installed under PHP 7.3 on macOS Catalina?

Tags: php, macos

I have a Mac running Catalina. This includes PHP 7.3.11 which was installed by default - I haven't modified this in any way.

```
% php -v
PHP 7.3.11 (cli) (built: Jun  5 2020 23:50:40) ( NTS )
```

I was trying to run `composer install` to set up a CakePHP 4 project locally. This errors with

```
% composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for cakephp/cakephp 4.1.6 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[4.1.6].
    - cakephp/cakephp 4.1.6 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - cakephp/cakephp 4.1.6 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/debug_kit 4.3.7 requires cakephp/cakephp ^4.1 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[4.1.6].
    - Installation request for cakephp/debug_kit 4.3.7 -> satisfiable by cakephp/debug_kit[4.3.7].
```

I've created `/etc/php.ini` and I can see this is being loaded:

```
% php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

The `php.ini` I created was a copy of `php.ini.default` which came with my Mac. This had the following line commented out

```
;extension=intl
```

I've uncommented this and saved as `/etc/php.ini`.

Now, I'm getting another error when executing `php` which says:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/intl (dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/intl, 0x0009): dlopen(): file not found: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/intl), /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/intl.so (dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/intl.so, 0x0009): dlopen(): file not found: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/intl.so)) in Unknown on line 0
```

How do you get `intl` extension installed under this environment? I've read that it should be included anyway by default in this version of PHP. Is this some Apple specific problem, or is there a workaround?

I found a solution (https://medium.com/@agaetis/solved-install-intl-php-extension-for-xampp-and-magento-for-macos-mojave-41fa42336fc6) using `brew` but this is for PHP 7.1, and doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Is this link related (1 year) ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55301299/mac-os-intl-extension-is-not-loaded

Comment: I dont use 'shipped' versions of anything with OSuX ... brew php, it will have intl bundled in.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg it seems the issue is that the version of PHP 7.3 shipped with macOS Catalina doesn't include the "intl" extension. The workaround I used was installing Homebrew and then switching back to PHP 7.3 as it installed PHP 8. There's a guide here https://medium.com/@romaninsh/install-php-7-2-xdebug-on-macos-high-sierra-with-homebrew-july-2018-d7968fe7e8b8 that a colleague gave me that works well if anyone comes across this post.

Comment: A search revealed this, also having the solution to use brew: [Mac OS: Intl extension is not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55301299/mac-os-intl-extension-is-not-loaded)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a docker image with apache and php (google : docker apache php github), set your project as a volume of your docker container with an external database or use this docker to build a new image with a DB.