# PHP 7.1 ext-intl* issue with Mac Mojave

Tags: macos, laravel-5, composer-php, macos-mojave

I bought new mac book air, and I want to set up PHP for working on some projects of mine. So, I want to install apiato framework and this is the error that I get from terminal:

> Zdravkos-MacBook-Air:Desktop zdravkolukic$ composer create-project apiato/apiato my-api
>   Installing apiato/apiato (v7.4.7)
>     - Installing apiato/apiato (v7.4.7): Loading from cache
>   Created project in my-api
>   @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - The requested PHP extension ext-intl * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.

But the major thing is this

> Problem 1
>       - The requested PHP extension ext-intl * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.

I try everything uninstall @php7.1 and install again, pecl install intl update, change icu4u everything!

Please help so, I can work. I have the latest version Mac Os Mojave.

P.S. when I type for a composer to install laravel everything is just fine

Thank you

Comment: Check these resources:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46652968/install-intl-php-extension-osx-high-sierra
2. https://medium.com/@crmcmullen/how-to-install-php-on-macos-10-13-high-sierra-and-10-14-mojave-using-homebrew-and-pecl-ef2276db3d62

Comment: i´ve had the same problem. You can try what worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55024726/fatal-error-ext-standard-php-smart-str-h-file-not-found and let me know if you need more details