# Why is composer install giving an errror after mac catalina update?

Tags: php, composer-php, contao

So I have just cloned a Contao based project on my Mac, and as I am setting it up i ran ´composer install´, before I updated to macOSX Catalina i never have this issue but now I am getting the following error, any ideas on fixing this? I am lost!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message already says, the PHP `intl` extension is not enabled for the PHP CLI environment that you used.

If you used the system's PHP and Apache packages, your previous configuration might have been deleted/overridden by the MacOS update. This is known to happen.

Comment: Thank you! For anyone interested, this proved to be a good tutorial (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46652968/install-intl-php-extension-osx-high-sierra)! What ultimately did the trick for me however was switiching to MAMP's PHP rather than using the Mac OS X default one (https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/5987693)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i solve it by reinstalling the command line tools

- open your Terminal
- write the command below

  $ xcode-select --install

so how i solve it