# Is there a way to fix php-intl missing?

Tags: php, xampp, homebrew, mediawiki, icu

I am trying on my Mac to have a mediawiki project on a localhost server through XAMPP, and when opening my project, the setup page requires I install php-intl.

Note that I am not familiar with this field at all so I might need extra help

I have tried the installing php and icu through homebrew, and manually downloading the dll file, and trying to edit the php.ini file as instructed to go to the respective file/folder, without much luck. It does not seem installing php or icu through homebrew that it actually includes an intl thing.

Only thing i'm left wondering if this should be solved in the phpmyadmin page.

Comment: Would this help you?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46652968/install-intl-php-extension-osx-high-sierra

Comment: *"the dll file"* A DLL is for Windows, not macOS.

Comment: I tried everything, and now it seems like i've made things worse.